# Why won't Angular log to Firebug console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console, firebug

My codebase/dev environment has developed the following issue at some point in the last week or two:

***Any error that is thrown by my javascript within Angular's realm of control doesn't get logged to the Firebug console.***

============================

## Details and Investigation:

I've tried both of the following for testing:

```
var x;
var y = x.test();
```

and

```
throw new Error('test');
```

I would *expect* that both of these should behave in essentially the same way: JS stops executing and console prints an error message.
In all cases in my testing both of these *have* behaved the same, so I'll just use the throw example below.

If I just throw at the start of an Angular script being included on a page (i.e. a `.js` file, which happens to make use of angular, and is in a `<script>` tag. Then I **DO** get my error.
e.g.

```
var app = angular.module("AbiApp", []);

console.log('test1');       // I see this.
throw new Error('test2');   // I DO see this.
console.log('test3');       // I don't see this. (as expected)

app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
});
```

If I through an error in a callback inside my Angular code (i.e. somewhere that isn't in Angular's normal realm of control; somewhere that I'd have to add $apply() to have changes be immediately updated) then, again, I **DO**  get my Error, at the relevant point.
e.g.

```
var app = angular.module("AbiApp", []);

app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // We're using SignalR
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log('test1');       // I see this.
        throw new Error('test2');   // I DO see this.
        console.log('test3');       // I don't see this. (as expected)
    });
});
```

But If I throw my error inside Angular's code (e.g. at the top the definition function of a controller) or if I deliberately mis-spell one of the dependencies for an Angular object. Then I **DO NOT** get any error on the console, but JS **DOES** stop executing.
e.g.

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log('test1');       // I see this.
    throw new Error('test2');   // I don't see this. :(
    console.log('test3');       // I don't see this.
});
```

or

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scpe', function ($scope) {
                     //            *****         No error thrown.
    console.log('test1');       // I don't see this.
});
```

If I repeat in Chrome, then I get all my errors back.
If I disable Firebug and open the Firefox Console, then I get all my errors back.

So I conclude that Angular has decided that it doesn't like my Firebug console, and therefore isn't logging to it unless I directly invoke `console.log()`. WTF?

I've tried:

- rolling back my code base to a commit from several weeks ago, when I'm 90% sure it was all working fine.
- restarting Firefox.
- restarting computer.
- reinstalling Firebug.

No changes to symptoms in any of those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't at all satisfactory, but I solve the problem by factory resetting Firebug.

The [Firebug FAQ](https://getfirebug.com/faq) has a specific entry on "[How do I reset all Firebug options](https://getfirebug.com/faq/#How_do_I_reset_all_Firebug_options)":
Firebug Menu > Options > Reset All Firebug Options

Now I have all the errors in all the places.

If anyone is able to make a guess about what setting it might have been that I got into the wrong state I be keen to hear it!